# FbGraph: Facebook events have a map, but the venue returned is not geolocated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I'm not sure it's a fbgraph bug. In fact I'm pretty sure it's not, but I would like to understand **why some facebook events display a map, but when I fetch them with FbGraph, the venue returned has no venue information**.

I'm doing:

```
FbGraph::Event.fetch("1314214...", access_token: "ABABZ...")
```

And the venue, which is part of the response, is

```
@venue=#<FbGraph::Venue:0x007f8657de20a8 @latitude=nil, @longitude=nil, @street=nil, @city=nil, @state=nil, @zip=nil, @country=nil>
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook will show a map even if the event creator never supplied geo-location data. So, if you don't receive location data it's because the event creator never supplied the data.

**Added: Relevant info from the discussion below...**

Facebook may draw a map of a given address by converting that address to latitude/longitude, however, you as the programmer don't have access to those coordinates. Facebook will only return coordinates if the user specifically entered them (usually by choosing a point on a map).

**Added: so maybe the above is wrong...**

After re-reading your question, I realize that my answer may not apply to your situation. It looks like what Facebook is actually doing is returning the location ID and leaving it up to you to query info about that place. Keep in mind that Facebook used to store events in it's database with individual data fields for address, city, state, etc. However, Facebook seems to be slowly transitioning to store only place ID's. (But it still has those fields available to programmers).

It used to be that you could programmatically create an event with a street, city, state, etc. Now, the only field you can supply is the place ID. The same goes with the event creation front-end from your *events* page -- you must find a place which Facebook recognizes, you can't simply enter an arbitrary address.

However, **if** you create an event programmatically and then go to edit it from Facebook you will find that you **can** enter an address manually.

Comment: Well, from what I understand, when you create an event, you have 2 choices: entering a location name yourself (and even if it's a valid address, the map wont show up), or choosing from the autocompletion results (and the map shows up). Are you saying that some places that show up in the autocompletion are in fact not geolocated? (how does an event creator supply the geolocation data otherwise?)

Comment: What I have noticed is that if you don't add the geolocation data, the map may not show up immediately, but after a few minutes Facebook figures it out and shows it.

Comment: **Are you saying that some places that show up in the autocompletion are in fact not geolocated?** That's not exactly what I was saying but I suspect that to be true as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "add the geolocation data"? When I try to create an event, all I have is a "Where" field, that's it. About the map showing up after a few minutes, it actually makes a lot of sense, if they do in fact geolocate the location entered, it would be in a background job for sure.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that Facebook changed it's interface to add an Event from the events page. **However**, the old event-management interface still exists which **may** mean that they both operate on the same type of system for the back-end. (When I create an event programmatic-ally from my app, it defaults to the old interface) That is, the old way allowed you to enter an address, geo-data, etc separately, but it was all pretty much optional. The new way requires a place. Nevertheless, **there is no reason to believe that all places necessarily have geo data**.

Comment: `if they do in fact geolocate the location entered`
 Yes, Facebook draws a map of a given address by converting that address to latitude/longitude, however I don't believe that you as the programmer can request those coordinates. Facebook will only return to you coordinates if the user specifically entered them (usually by choosing a point on a map)

Comment: `however I don't believe that you as the programmer can request those coordinates` I'm sure you can, fbgraph returns the lat/lng for some events (I'm using this in prod already), and looking at the api, it's supposed to be available. What I dont really understand is that, when I create a fake event with a location chosen in facebook's places, facebook still does not return the lat/lng sometimes... (Thanks for your answers)

Comment: I can't tell if we're disagreeing, or if my explanation was unclear. Are you saying that you have received coordinates for an event based on a place that _never had coordinates entered by a user_?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I'm pretty confident that the creators of the events imported to my site did not enter the coordinates themselves.

Comment: Maybe that was the confusion, when I say that the owner of the venue (or event creator) "enters coordinates" I mean that they are clicking on a bing map in Facebook and that is how the coordinates get set. In this way, Facebook makes it very easy to set the coordinates. However, in the past I think that it wasn't so easy and many people ended up not setting coordinates. Venues that were configured back then may not have the coordinates now.

Comment: I also posted the question on the github of fbgraph, and it seems like facebook does not return what FbGraph expects. Nov will take a look at the issue. (https://github.com/nov/fb_graph/issues/211 if you're interested)